# svgo shape to path do not convert ellipses

Tags: node.js, svg, svgo

Trying to use svgo to batch convert shapes to paths from svg files.

https://github.com/svg/svgo

```
svgo --version
1.2.0
```

looklike ellipse element are not converted to paths

made test on commande line like :

```
➜ svg svgo --enable=convertShapeToPath 1.svg

➜ svg svgo --enable=convertShapeToPath --config=conf.json --pretty 1.svg
```

with config.json having

```
{ "convertArcs": true }
```

also tried with

```
"plugins": [
    {
  "name": "convertShapeToPath",
  "params": {
    "convertArcs": true
  }
},
```

also tried

```
{
  "pretty": true,
  "multipass": true,
  "floatPrecision": 2,
  "plugins": [
    {
      "name": "convertShapeToPath",
      "enabled": true,
      "params": {
        "convertArcs": true
      }
    }  
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this question? You've raised it on the [site's issue tracker](https://github.com/svg/svgo/pull/818) which is probably where I'd point you to.

Comment: @RobertLongson What do i want to achieve ? maybe find someone that already face that problem and who may help, isn't that stackoverflow purpose ?

Comment: @RobertLongson according to this :

https://github.com/svg/svgo/pull/818/commits/0f86c7028b132701ef599bb3280381a6dadb2d91 

it's not a bug.

I may have missed something in my config. Don't be so pessimistic

Comment: for now i edited plugin source :

exports.params = {
    convertArcs: true
};

in convertShapeToPath.js and it works so it doesn't sound to be a bug

Answer (score 1):

Finally it has to do with configuration object format that must be as follow :

```
"plugins": 
[{ 
    "convertShapeToPath": 
    { 
        "convertArcs": true 
    } 
}]
```